# SPV1050 Harvester IC MPPT Setup

Tags: solar-charge-controller

I have been trying to use SPV1050 Harvester IC with a solar panel to charge a Li-Ion battery. However I am having problem deciding the resistor values for the MPPT pins. In section 6.4-MPPT Setting of [the datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/spv1050.pdf), below constraint is given:

$$
V_{MPP(MAX)} \leq 2.1 V.
$$

However, \$V_{MPP(MAX)}\$ in STEVAL-ISV021V1 that uses SPV1050 is designed to be around 3.16 V. I would appreciate if anyone can explain the reason for such discrepancy.

P.S. The calculation of 3.16 V is below:
$$
R1 = R_{IN(TOT)} \times \left(1 - \frac{V_{MPP(MAX)}}{{V_{OC(MAX)}}}\right)
$$

Hence:

$$
V_{MPP(MAX)} = V_{OC(MAX)} \times \left(1 - \frac{R1}{R_{IN(TOT)}}\right)\\
= 9.8\times1.2\times\left(1-\frac{10}{13.68}\right)\
=3.16 V
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe section 6.4 is partly an application example where they derive the 2.1 V limit from the value of \$V_\mathit{UVP(MIN)}\$.

The actual constraint (section 5) is \$V_\mathit{MPP} \le V_\mathit{UVP} - 0.1\$, and maximum absolute rating is 5.5 V. This would make \$V_\mathit{MPP(MAX)}\$ dependent on the choice of \$V_\mathit{UVP}\$ for a particular application.

I agree it's a little bit confusing and it's possible the datasheet mistakenly uses \$V_\mathit{UVP(MIN)}\$ instead of \$V_\mathit{UVP}\$.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my initial thoughts. This is exactly how I decided to proceed.